# Build array from MySQL query to format json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

i've a problem to build the right array from mysql result for the expected json format:

table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `Config_Category` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `topid` INT(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
    ;
```

filled table:

```
id  name        topid
2   DVD         1
3   Matrix      2
4   CD          1
5   Deep Purple 4
6   Pink Floyd  4
7   Batman      2
```

```
MyClass
{
    public function getMenu($topid)
    {

        $stmt = $this->pdoDash->query("SELECT id,name 
            FROM Config_Category WHERE topid='$topid'");

        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($results as $row)
        {
            if ($this->hasChildKats($row['id']))
            {
                $path[] = array("group" => $row['name']);
                $path[] = array_merge($this->getMenu($row['id'], $path));

            } else
            {
                $path["item"][] = array("name" => $row['name']);

            }
        }
        return $path;
    }

    private function hasChildKats($katID)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdoDash->query("SELECT count(*) 
            FROM Config_Category WHERE topid='$katID'");

        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
    }
}

$this->test = new MyClass;
echo json_encode($this->test->getMenu());
```

my result:

```
[
{
    "group": "DVD"
},
{
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Matrix"
        },
        {
            "name": "Batman"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "group": "CD"
},
{
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Pink Floyd"
        },
        {
            "name": "Deep Purple"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

expected result:

```
[
{
    "group": "DVD",
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Matrix"
        },
        {
            "name": "Batman"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "group": "CD",
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Pink Floyd"
        },
        {
            "name": "Deep Purple"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that using empty brackets [] is what is causing this behavior. You should try with a variable as a counter:

```
var $counter = 0;

foreach ($results as $row)
{
    if ($this->hasChildKats($row['id']))
    {
        $path[$counter] = array("group" => $row['name']);
        $path[$counter] = array_merge($this->getMenu($row['id'], $path));

    } else
    {
        $path["item"][$counter] = array("name" => $row['name']);
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: the counter is not the trick.
the group name will not be shown in the output

Answer (score 0):

I come across DB access patterns like this a lot.  And I can usually speed them up by 100x or more.  It seems like you're hitting the DB at least once per row in the menu printed out.  Yet this can be solved in a single DB call and a PHP loop.

Here's an example of how that would work.  (might not exactly match your data model).
Note: I always name arrays of items in the plural so i changed 'item' to 'items' on purpose

```
public function getMenu($topid) {

    $stmt = $this->pdoDash->query("SELECT id, name, topid FROM Config_Category");
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $path = array();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        if ($row['topid'] == 1) {   // top level category
            $path[$row['id']] = array();
            $path[$row['id']]['group'] = row['name'];
        } else {    // child category
            $path[$row['topid']]['items'][] = array('name'=>row['name']);
        }
    }
    return $path;
}
```